# "Trip preferences", database design

Tags: database-design

I'm looking to create a database for store trips. The trips have a `Location`, a `Mode` and a `Preferences`. (All of them are entities, or classes). Let's now assume each `Trip` can have only one `Preferences` and a `Preferences` can be part of several trips.

Now, I have modeled it in this way:

```
Trips(id, attr1, attr2, ..., prefs);
Preferences(id, pref1, pref2, pref3);
```

Where 'prefs' is a FK (and pref1, pref2 and pref3 are boolean types).

Ok, when I store a trip (with id = 1) with pref1, pref2 and pref3 to true, and another trip (with id = 2) with the same preferences values, I will have something like this:

```
+------+----+-------+-----+---------------+
| Trip | id | attr1 | ... | prefs         |
+------+----+-------+-----+---------------+
|      | 1  |   X   | ... | 10            |
+------+----+-------+-----+---------------+
|      | 2  |   X   | ... | 20            |
+------+----+-------+-----+---------------+


+-------------+------+-------+-------+---------+
| Preferences | id   | pref1 | pref2 | pref3   |
+-------------+------+---------------+---------+
|             |  10  |  True | True  | True    |
+-------------+------+---------------+---------+
|             |  20  |  True | True  | True    |
+-------------+------+---------------+---------+
```

And the questions is: Isn't there a lot of redundancy? Suppose I store 100 trips with the same preferences values, then I will have 100 rows in `Preferences` table with the same values.

Maybe is a problem that concerns to my application and not to my database design?

Thanks.

(Sorry for my basic English).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like your design is properly normalized and is therefore likely to be inefficient or to cause you some data maintenance headaches.

It is a little bit hard to tell from your question, but it seems like `pref1`, `pref2` and `pref3` are different things or states that might apply or not apply to each trip.  If you have a finite number of things which are there or not there for each trip then you are probably better off treating the things (preferences) as rows of their own table and using an intersection table to indicate which ones apply to each trip.

Something like this:

```
Trips
( id
, attr1
, attr2
)

Preferences
( id
, description
)

Trip_Preferences
( trip_id
, preference_id
, value  -- If the value is true/false, then you have the option of leaving this out
         -- and just using the presence or absense of a record in this table as the
         -- indication of the value.
)
```

Such a design is a better option as it eliminates redundancy and it is more flexible for the future should you decide to expand the number of preferences that could apply to a trip.

Comment: Thanks! I think your design is fine.